# Derivative not integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Is there a function which is differentiable but whose derivative cannot be integrated again to get the original function, i.e. something like

Given $f(x)$, $f'(x)$ exists, but we cannot integrate $f'(x)$ to get $f(x)$?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function).

Comment: Okay, the reason I am asking is: Assume we have an IVP $\frac{d}{dt}u(t,x)=f(u), u(0,x)=u_0$. Then, we can write this equivalently as an integral equation for fixed x, namely $u(t,x)=u_0+\int_0^t f(u(s,x))\, dx$. Now, setting $(Fu)(t)=u_0+\int_0^t f(u(s,x))\, dx$, we have that $u$ solves the original IVP iff $u$ is a fixed point of $F$. Now, on which function space should we define $F$? First I thought of the space of all differentiable functions; but then we might have the problem the we cannot integrate the derivative? So better choose $F: C^1\to C^1$?

Comment: Maybe it is even enough to have $F\colon C^0\to C^0$.